# don't have permission to save the file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-x

Recently i'm using cocos **2d-x ver-3.17**.

I complied resource to jsc then make a server to upload it like update-server, control version i think.
Now when i build the app in IOS which will connect to update-server then download the file jsc. Unfortunately, when the app trying to save the file down it falling to the error " don't have permission to save the file". What should i do to provide them permission to solve it.

> Fail to create directory :
>   "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9BA91B9-AEF6-4FF8-B5F3-061AF15441A5/Documents_temp/":
>   You don’t have permission to save the file “Documents_temp” in the
>   folder “C9BA91B9-AEF6-4FF8-B5F3-061AF15441A5”.

```
bool FileUtilsApple::createDirectory(const std::string& path)
{
    CCASSERT(!path.empty(), "Invalid path");

    if (isDirectoryExist(path))
        return true;

    NSError* error;

    bool result = [s_fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

    if(!result && error != nil)
    {
        CCLOGERROR("Fail to create directory \"%s\": %s", path.c_str(), [error.localizedDescription UTF8String]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

How can i get permission to save the files ?

Answer (score 0):

solved : https://forum.cocos.com/t/topic/47298/3 
Self-reliance, find out the problem, you need to define the file directory

> find your initAssetManager :

```
var storagePath = (jsb.fileUtils ? jsb.fileUtils.getWritablePath() : "./")+"temp/";
```